# What is Instruction Per Second?

Tags: c++, for-loop, console

Does instruction per second means total calculations perform in a second?
How can I get total ISP in a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions Per Second is a concept that indeed counts the instructions executed in one second. The concept fell out of favor in the last decade of the previous century, for many reasons. The core reason was the figure was meaningless.

You can't meaningfully calculate the "IPS" for a `for`-loop in C++. It's rather unclear what the actual instructions would be for a complex loop, and trivial loops are optimized out entirely. E.g. calculating N! might look like a for-loop, but the compiler could just decide to turn 7! in 5040.

Comment: So what really does an instruction mean? 1+2=3, would this be 3 instructions?

Comment: @BongBong: That isn't even valid C++.